# Need loop that will repeat as long as the user needs it to C#

Tags: c#, loops

Here is the code I have, I know it's ugly, but I am very new, what I am trying to figure out it how to keep the loop repeating until the user is finished, and chooses to exit. The purpose is to enter employee name, pay rate, and hours worked, save them to a list, then ask the user if they need to add another user, or if not edit a user, or exit the program.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static string Name()
    {
        string name;

        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

        Console.Write("What is the employees name? ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        nameList.Add(name);

        return "";
    }

    private static int Numbers()
    {
        int hours;
        int pay;
        int payroll;

        List<int> payList = new List<int>();
        List<int> hoursList = new List<int>();

        Console.Write("What is the pay rate for the employee? ");
        pay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        payList.Add(pay);

        Console.Write("How many hours did the employee work? ");
        hours = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        hoursList.Add(hours);

        payroll = pay * hours;
        Console.Write("Pay the employee: " + payroll);

        return pay;            
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Name();
        Numbers();

        Console.Write("\nDo you need to add another employee? Y or N\n");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (choice == "Y")
        {
            Name();
            Numbers();
            Console.Write("\nDo you need to add another employee? Y or N\n");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if(choice == "N")
            {
                    Console.Write("\nDo you want to edit (E) an entry, or exit (X) the program? ");
                    string secondChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (secondChoice == "X")
                    {
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    if (secondChoice == "E")
                    {
                        Name();
                        Numbers();
                    }                    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("\nDo you want to edit (E) an entry, or exit (X) the program? ");
            string secondChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (secondChoice == "X")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if(secondChoice == "E")
            {
                Name();
                Numbers();                        
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
 }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't contain any loop at all

Comment: Just add while(true) to complete code block in the main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is a recursive while loop with some logic in to handle asking the right questions based on the current state. We could give you a direct answer here but you really need to understand some core and simple principles first.

I would then recommend you take a look at my C# beginners videos here https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrW43fNmjaQXhWOKalftye87ObZA-xNIJ

Specifically, what would help is this video on While loops and complex logic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4g8JHX5jgg

From that you should be able to answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, I would recomend you take a look at some basic loop tutorials, for example one of these

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_do_while_loop.htm
- https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/loop-constructs/

But there are many more out there.

To answer your question directly you could use some structure like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      while(true) //loop forever
      {
        Console.WriteLine("do you want to (A)dd (E)dit or (X) Exit?");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice == "A")
        {
          //Do add stuff here
        } 
        else if (choice == "E")
        {
          //Do edit stuff here
        } 
        else if (choice == "X")
        {
          break; //exit the loop
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("unknown command");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You basically enter an endless loop, where the user always gets asked the same question, depending on his answer you do your different stuff. If the user wants to exit, you just have to break the loop.
Instead of such a if-else chain you could alternatively use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new void and in the end call the void again
for example:

```
 static void Main(string args[]){
     Loop();
 }  

 private static void Loop(){
     //code...

    //in the end
    Loop();
 }
```

You don't need a while loop unless you will do it in another thread.